# iOS 7 UISearchDisplayController search bar overlaps status bar while searching

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, ios7, statusbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm updating my app for iOS 7, and I'm in the process of adjusting all my views to account for the new transparent status bar (my app will still use opaque navigation bars).

It was relatively easy to adjust for the status bar in every view, except one major problem I'm having with a UISearchBar connected to a UISearchDisplayController in one of my view controllers.

The search bar seems to display normally, as shown below:

[image: Search Bar]

The problem is, as soon as I begin searching, the navigation bar disappears (as it should), but everything else also moves up to overlap the status bar:

[image: Broken Search Bar]

This doesn't appear to be working as intended, since the darkening of the screen happens 20 pixels below the search bar, where the search bar should end.

Is there a built in solution for this in iOS 7? I'd rather not have to manually adjust the frame for every view each time the user begins and ends searching.

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to point out that I have a search display controller and search bar in another view, attached to a UITableViewController, which transitions fine. Maybe that has something to do with the problem?

Comment: i  have the same problem, any update for this topic?

Comment: I have the same setup and the same issue.

Comment: I think it is related to being the first view in a navigationcontroller hierarchy. For instance this only happens in the view associated with a tab on the tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thank you hodade for leading me on the right track! Your solution worked, except it only moved the search bar's frame, leaving my other subviews in the wrong spot. The only thing I changed was to move all the subviews in my view, as well as animate it.

Thanks!

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
                subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, statusBarFrame.size.height);
        }];
    }
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
                subview.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: This and hodade's answer did not help me. It still automatically moves the searchbar up.

Comment: Upon further review this seems like a timing issue. Using DidBeginSearch will make it animate under the status bar then go back down some more...

Comment: With out adding anything its working for me in iOS7 in some cases..but in one case its not working..what is the reason?why we need to write the above code?

Answer (score 88):

Putting the following line in the viewDidLoad fixed it for me:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: If you're going this route, `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight;` is probably a better and more general solution assuming your search bar is at the top of the screen. (This will preserve the extended layout for other edges, which is important for things like toolbars with blurring at the bottom of the screen.)

Comment: just check [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)] to prevent a crash on < iOS 7.

Comment: @richy Didn't get your point. I'm getting error if same code is opened in Xcode 4.x.

Comment: Jayprakash XCode 4.x only supports iOS6.x and below so you will need to do `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]){self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;}`

Comment: This didn't work for me until I saw that view controllers have a reference for SearchDisplayControllers. Once I linked this in IB, it worked!

Comment: It should, I've tested it in a UISplitView.

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; work for me

Answer (score 13):

You're may using no translucent navigation bar?
If so, this will solve it.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Comment: self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; not works in my case thanks @tachiba

Answer (score 7):

Just place following code in **-(void) ViewDidLoad**. It will work for iOS 7 and later version

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"6.1")) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Salim! This solution works for a UISearchBar embedded in a UIViewController that is opened as a popup on iPad/iPhone6+.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to describe the problem I was having; hopefully it will help someone in my former positon.

1. Subclass your SearchDisplayController that's been added to your UIViewController/UITablewViewController,
2. Add something like this to its implementation:

   ```
    - (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super setActive:visible animated:animated];

       [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: NO];

       CGRect frame = self.searchResultsTableView.frame;
       frame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(self.searchContentsController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);

       frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMinY(frame);

       self.searchResultsTableView.frame = frame;

       frame = self.searchBar.frame;
       self.searchBar.frame = frame;

       [self.searchContentsController.view insertSubview:self.searchBar aboveSubview:self.searchResultsTableView];

   }
   ```

Comment: Awesome, this works on iOS7 (and 8) in simulator.  Don't know why this isn't higher.

Answer (score 6):

I did below code to solve the problem.

```
    - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
         if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)
        {
            CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
            CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
            viewBounds.origin.y = topBarOffset * -1;
            self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
        }
}
```

Comment: I suspect, this should go into a UISearchDisplayController subclass? This does not have a view property.

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe add this to viewDidLoad will help:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}
```

Comment: Or actually set flag to adjust them for table view

Answer (score 3):

just add

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

you can read more from here: [UISearchController and definesPresentationContext](http://programmingthomas.com/blog/2014/10/5/uisearchcontroller-and-definespresentationcontext)

and from Apple documentation: [UISearchController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/definesPresentationContext)

**Note:** UISearchDispalyController is deprecated in iOS7, use UISearchController instead in iOS8, method above use UISearchController

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the views below the search bar were at their right place, only the search bar was overlapping the status bar. In this case, this peace of code works fine:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {        
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        CGRect frame = self.searchBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y += statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.searchBar.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        CGRect frame = self.searchBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= statusBarFrame.size.height;
        self.searchBar.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        CGRect frame = controller.searchBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y += statusBarFrame.size.height;
        controller.searchBar.frame = frame;
    }
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
        CGRect frame = controller.searchBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= statusBarFrame.size.height;
        controller.searchBar.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers only work if you have your **navigation bar unhidden**. If you have your **navigation bar hidden** try this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y+statusBarFrame.size.height, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height)];

    }
}
```

Based on this post: [UISearchBar overlaps status bar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975920/uisearchbar-overlaps-status-bar-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your `SearchDisplayController` that's been added to your `UIViewController/UITablewViewController` and add this to its implementation -

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.active == visible) return;
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    if (visible) {
        [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```