# Presenting UISearchController overlaps with statusbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UISearchController` which I present programmatically when the user touches a button. My problem is that the search bar overlaps the status (see screenshot)

[image]

I have the following code which I use to present the `UISearchController`

```
func presentSearchController() {
    let resultsController = ResultsViewController()

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .prominent

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController

    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    self.present(self.searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Edit: My question is not a duplicate of [UISearchBar overlaps status bar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975920) as I am not working directly with the searchbar or it's frame

Comment: Its look like you have place search bar frame from `CGRectMake (0,0,width,hright)`  in th vc? right?

Comment: I have faced same issue just before half an hour.

Comment: @Mukesh I have resolved the issue. See my answer below

Comment: Okay great :D i have change my rect. for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved the issue by remove the following line:

`self.definesPresentationContext = true`

The reason this is not required in my scenario is that I am calling     `self.present(self.searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

UPDATE:

While the above did fix my issue, it broke the functionality of pushing a viewController in my navigationController while the SearchController was displayed (the searchController would stay on top while the viewController was pushed underneath it)

Upon revisiting the issue, here are the fixes I made:

Add the following

`searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
self.definesPresentationContext = true`

Then in the storyboard enable "Under Top Bars" and enable "Under Opaque Bars"