# UISearchBar going to the view's top when I click on it

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableView which doesn't reach the entire view. Approximatively, the UITableView is two times smaller than the view.

Then, I add *"Search Bar and Search Display Controller"* to the UITableView from the *Object library*. So, to visualize, the searchBar appears at the screen's center.

**Here's my view :**

[image]

**My problem :** When I click into the search field to do my research, the searchBar is going to the top of the view, in place of the navigation bar ! And the transition is very awful... How can I constraint the searchBar to stay in its initial place ?

Comment: Have the same exact problem and I was going to ask for it toady. The search bar is intended to move to the top but the problem is the empty space it leaves on the table. I believe since the controller's view is not solely a table view then the search bar cannot manipulate the table view directly to move up and cover the empty space

Comment: @giorashc have you set frame for self.searchDisplayController or self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView. Try setting frame for it.. and let me know –

Comment: Use simple UISearchBar instead of UISearchDisplayController

Comment: @the1pawan I tried moving the table view by modifying its frame but it didn't work. In my case I do not care that the search bar is on top but the empty space it leaves in the table view is my problem

Comment: @AshutoshMishra The problem does not appear when using only UISearchBar. But without using UISearchDisplayController, you can't access to delegate methods like **shouldReloadTableForSearchString** or **shouldReloadTableForSearchScope**...

Comment: @Erzékiel- you can make your custom own too

Comment: @Erzékiel you do not need to force those methods, there are alternatives

Comment: OK, anyway, I would like to keep the Search Display Controller in place. Why the searchBar is going on top and leave an unsightly blank ?

Comment: please look at this link, it seems same issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18988959/2482283

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to the search display controller. You don't have the control over the animation and it doesn't seem to handle it well when there's a view sitting on top of your TableView. We had the same exact problem and the easiest way we fixed it is by replacing the Search Display Controller by a simple Search Bar in the Storyboard.

That means your class will now have to implement the delegate method of the search bar to work properly.

To animate properly, simply override the **searchBarTextDidBeginEditing** and **searchBarTextDidEndEditing** like so:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.origin.y = tableViewFrame.origin.y - self.yourHeaderView.bounds.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{ self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame; }];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
tableViewFrame.origin.y = tableViewFrame.origin.y + self.yourHeaderView.bounds.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{ self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame; }];
}
```

Simply put, you just move the table view frame over the view based on it's height. The animation makes it smoother and cleaner.