# UISearchDisplayController changing frame

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

i'm using UISearchDisplayController in my ViewController: [image]

search bar is part of my tableView:

[image]

All works fine (search,search results) but i have one issue: when i'm pressing search her it becomes bigger, and after i'm pressing cancel button it changes his position and returns to initial position, please check this [Picture](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/12-10-2013/YPdEFL.gif). What am i missing? I just hooked up my searchDisplayController with storyboard, and using some code for search, i'm not changing size or position of my searchBar.

Comment: This search field is part of your table view ?

Comment: try to remove the searchDisplayController and add only searchBar

Comment: i want to use search display controller, because i'm updating my searchResultsTableView in searchDisplayController

Comment: are you manually changing he size of the table view ?

Comment: no, it's set in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` in viewDidLoad helped me:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) 
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeLeft | UIRectEdgeBottom | UIRectEdgeRight;
else
    [self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)];
```

**WARNING: This only works on iOS >= 7**

Source:

- [iOS 7 UISearchDisplayController search bar overlaps status bar while searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925900/ios-7-uisearchdisplaycontroller-search-bar-overlaps-status-bar-while-searching)