# UISearchDisplayController Results Table Overlapping UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm having a strange issue with my `UISearchDisplayController`. When the search display activates the frame of the background fading view and the `tableview` are incorrectly overlapping the `UISearchBar`. It appears the results `tableview` is not taking the offset for the `UIStatusBar` into account.

The `ViewController` is using `auto layout`. Since the application does not use any opaque bars, the view controller does not extend any of its edges.

```
 Extend edges under top bars = NO, 
 under bottom bars = NO, and
 under opaque bars = NO.
```

**Here is the initial layout:**

[image: Initial Layout]

**This is what happens when the search display activates:**

[image: Activated Search]

**And finally, here is the resulting output of the search:**

[image: Search Results]

Comment: fadingView, you bring it over the tableview as subView or you present it over `UITableView` ?

Comment: The UISearchDisplayController handles this automatically. I am not configuring it's actual presentation in any specific way. I simply have delegate/datasource methods for populating the table in my view controller.

Comment: I had this in iOS7 only, when I used presentViewController for popping up a Mail Box. It has to be presented over the window and I was using it over the view detached.

Comment: Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925900/ios-7-uisearchdisplaycontroller-search-bar-overlaps-status-bar-while-searching

Comment: No I've already reviewed that question. He had the opposite problem. His search results are displaying in the proper position, but his search bar was rendering incorrectly, underneath the status bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem. A hard lesson learned. After a few hours of thinking "It really shouldn't be this hard." I realized that my instance of UISearchDisplayController was not properly linked to the API provided property of its parent view controller. If you're using UIStoryBoards / Interface Builder be sure to click on your ViewController and view its provided outlets in the inspector. If you see this:

[image: Missing Outlet]

Then something is wrong and you're going to run into issues just as I had. What you'll want to do is to click in that empty circle and drag to your instance of the Search Display Controller. If things are linked up right you should see this:

[image: Correct Link]

I foolishly didn't pay attention to this and created my own IBOutlet to reference the Search Display controller. That caused IB to null out the API provided outlet as a UIViewController can only support one Search Display Controller. If you need me to clarify anything let me know.